# Create .exe file from .py file Python 3.6 to create PDF standalone

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, cx-freeze, reportlab

I have a very simple .py program which uses a GUI built with tkinter to prompt the user for two numbers, and then prints the answer out in a PDF using 'from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas'. This is the code below.

```
from tkinter import *

def add_numbers():
    num1 = (e1.get())
    num2 = (e2.get())
    print(float(num1) + float(num2))

master = Tk()

# Modify the window
master.title("Add two numbers")
master.geometry("800x500")

Label(master, text = "Input parameters below:").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
Label(master, text="a = ").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=E)
Label(master, text = "mm").grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=W)
Label(master, text="b = ").grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=E)
Label(master, text = "mm").grid(row=3, column=2, sticky=W)
Label(master, text = "Press 'Input' & then 'Calculate'").grid(row=5, column=0)

e1 = Entry(master)
e2 = Entry(master)

e1.grid(row=2, column=1)
e2.grid(row=3, column=1)

Button(master, text='Input', command=add_numbers).grid(row=7, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)
Button(master, text='Calculate', command=master.quit).grid(row=8, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)


mainloop()

c2 = e1.get()
d2 = e2.get()

print(float(c2) * float(d2))

a1 = float(c2) * float(d2)


from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

c = canvas.Canvas("test1.pdf")
c.drawString(100,750, "a = " + c2)
c.drawString(100,730, "b = " + d2)
c.drawString(100,710, "area = " + str(a1) + "mm2")
c.save()
```

Is it possible to create a standalone .exe program where the user can generate a PDF from inputs in a tkinter GUI without having Python on their system? I am currently using the following code for my setup.py file:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

import os
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\Users\\bra\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\tcl\\tcl8.6"
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\Users\\bra\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\tcl\\tcl8.6"

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os","reportlab.pdfgen","tkinter"]}

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(  name = "my_first_prog.py",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "My GUI application!",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("my_first_prog.py", base=base)])
```

When I do this I can create a 'build' directory and I can find an 'application' type file which is called my_first_prog. I assume that this is the .exe file? When I click on it I get the following at the bottom: "import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk" and "ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found."

Is there anything easy that I'm missing here? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Maybe put `tkinter` in `includes` instead of `packages` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22006429/6209196)?

Comment: I'm assuming that you have tkinter installed across your whole system and not just in some virtual environment that you've been working in?

Comment: I just used the 'pip install....' in the command window. Does this mean it's not installed across the whole system? If not do I need to download something? (Apologies for my ignorance, I'm a complete novice).