# Can regular python input text be carried over when converted to .exe?

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame, cx-freeze

I'm working on a program that plays music and also plays a sound effect if you push a button. I was planning on making it so that it could work on any computer, with any sound effect and music file. So I tried making it an `.exe` with `cx_freeze`, but it just opens command prompt for a split second and then closes it again. Any tips?

```
import pygame, time
import tkinter as tk
from pygame.locals import *

print ("WARNING: The program only accepts .wav files.")
musicDir = input("What is the FULL address of the music? (e.g C:\\Me\\Music\\music.wav) ")
soundDir = input("What is the FULL address of the music? (e.g C:\\Me\\Music\\sound.wav) ")

pygame.init() # initialize the pygame

soundObj = pygame.mixer.Sound(musicDir)
soundObj.play(loops=-1)


def playSound():
    soundObj = pygame.mixer.Sound(soundDir)
    soundObj.play()


root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

button = tk.Button(frame, 
               text="QUIT", 
               fg="red",
               command=quit)
button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
sound = tk.Button(frame,
               text="Play Sound Effect",
               fg="green",
               command=playSound)
sound.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

instruction = tk.Button(root,
             text="Program by Will but really I just wanted another button because it looked cool.", 
             fg="blue")
instruction.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Drag the executable generated by cx_freeze into a command prompt, and paste the output in your question. There a variety of things that could be going wrong.

Comment: Tried dragging it in, same thing, flashes open then closed.

Comment: Put a print statement and the very beginning of your file, cx_freeze it again, and drag it into the terminal once more. See if it prints any messages or not.

Comment: Well the issue with the command prompt is fixed now, but as per usual with coding a new issue has arisen "File "C:\Python 3.6\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found."

Comment: I would guess that your build is incomplete. Perhaps [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22004721/creating-exe-file-with-cx-freeze-for-a-tkinter-interface) will help you to build your executable correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unable to do the same with cx_freeze, and my code works perfectly without the .exe. I have tried a few things on the internet, to solve the issue but in vain.

But, if you really want to make a .exe, one of the best options out there is pyinstaller. I use it all the time.

To install:

```
sudo -H pip3 install pyinstaller
```

To use:

```
pyinstaller test_file.py
```

After that is done, go to the "dist" directory and enter the folder named after your project.
In there, there will be quite a lot of files. But, there will be one .exe file, the one that you need. So, click on it to run.

If you want to input the address of a file don't use an entry, use the following (it looks good, and there will be no errors):

```
from tkinter import filedialog as fd

filename = fd.askopenfilename()
if filename:
    print (filename)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Did everything you said to install, and there seemed to be no issues, but when I try and use it it says 'pytinstaller : The term 'pytinstaller' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.'

Comment: Thanks! I just changed the Path and that fixed the issue with it not showing up! However, now an error comes up saying: "soundObj=pygame.mixer.Sound(musicDir)
pygame.error: Unable to open file 'C:\\Users\\Will\\Desktop\\program\\musicfile.wav' " Any tips?

Comment: My guess would be for some reason Python has put in double the backslashes into the string, as I tested this with "\\", which gave me "\\\\" and "\\\", which gave me "\\\\\\".

Comment: I have added the syntax for a filedialog, it'll help with the above error.. Please accept the answer if it was helpful. Happy to help! :)