# converting .py file to .exe file

Tags: python, mysql, opencv, tkinter, face-recognition

we have a face recognition module imported in our .py file, how to convert that .py file into executable file? and also we have some .txt files for which we gave project path itself. How to change that local path to global path and to convert to executable file?

Comment: if ur changing it to exe, its better to not use global path, because your username might not be same as some1 else's so its fine. and try the module `pyinstaller`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps for an executable file is as simple as below -
Install `cx_freeze` and then create a file `setup.py` and paste the following contents -

```
build_exe_options = {"includes": ["tkinter"]}
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"
```

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable 

setup(name = "<name-of-executable-file.exe>" , 
version = "<your-version-number>" , 
description = "<suitable-description>" ,
options={"build_exe": build_exe_options},
executables = [Executable("<your-python-file.py>", base=base)])
```

Run `python setup.py build` in your terminal.

Comment: i have seen some vids where this has some more extra code for tkinter? or it is going to generate errors?

Comment: For tkinter, refer the following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22004721/creating-exe-file-with-cx-freeze-for-a-tkinter-interface

Comment: no wat i mean is, the OP uses tkinter here

Comment: Do you want to run the tkinter application using a executable file or is there something else?

Comment: i mean the person who asked the Q is using tkinter as mentioned in his tags

Comment: Oh, I agree. The link [creating-exe-file-with-cx-freeze-for-a-tkinter-interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22004721/creating-exe-file-with-cx-freeze-for-a-tkinter-interface) addresses the same problem. For simplicity, I have added the code here.

Comment: okays, please mention it too :D

Comment: Thank you for both, we will try in this way,and we get any kind of issues further, will post here.

Answer (score 0):

So basically all you have to do is, open your terminal and (if not installed already)

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

then in the terminal you can tell,

```
pyinstaller -w -F -i"icon.ico" name_of_file.py
```

and this will start to compile an exe. So this exe is kept inside of a dist folder, you should copy that exe to the main directory(project path).

- Here `-w` means that the exe has to be windowed
- `-F` means that the exe has to be onefile only, u can make a whole directory with `-D`
- `-i'icon.ico'` refers to the icon file of your exe, it is relative to the path of terminal

For more flags and details refer [here](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html)

Cheers

Comment: what should i do if i get an error "Failed to execute script" after converting to `.exe`?

Comment: it could be due to plenty of reasons, like if there is an error in your code, it could be the reason

Comment: No I have checked the code and it works fine in the python interpreter. Is there a problem regarding version compatibility?

Comment: no issues like date, waht is the pyinstaller code used

Comment: `pyinstaller --onefile --windowed script.py`. Even though this yields an exe file, I cannot open it.

Comment: try this `pyinstaller --onefile -c script.py` and tell me what comes up in the console when u run the exe

Comment: it works but a part of the script still flashes the same error "Failed to execute script". Also I do not want a console to appear

Comment: the console is just to know where the error in the code appears, so u might have to take a look in the console to find out where the error and waht the error code is

Comment: I changed some functions and now it works. Thanks @Cool Cloud. So shall I again change it to `--windowed`?

Comment: yep try it on and let me know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219157/discussion-between-cool-cloud-and-pranav-krishna-s).

Comment: I have posted another issue in chat

Comment: ive replied too

Comment: Got it thanks a lot. Can we chat together ?

Comment: sadly,casual chatting is not what dis site is for :(